# Pushing fix to a released branch in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

I'm working on git lab project where I will be releasing master after every month. The integration environment will have my released version. The problem I'm facing here is to push bug fixes to previous release.
Say, I have a release 1.1 which is pushed into integration environment and I'm now working on release 1.2 where changes are pushed to master every day. However, I want to push some big fix to 1.1 and I don't want 1.2 changes to go with that bug fix. How can I achieve this? I thought of tagging the master branch with a release version. But when I want to do a bug fix, can I take a tagged version of the branch and push my fix into it? How does that work?
Is there an alternate solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to maintain a branch for each separate component you're developing and also use QA beach to merge your entire project and test that. If your code is working fine in the QA branch, then you can merge your branch with the master. If you want to go back to your previous commit, you can use git revert. also, you can keep a release branch for manage versions. If you having specific release issues and you merge your later developments to master, you can use the release branch to fix bugs that specific to a version.